# Can I register micro-frontends lazily after invoking start method from single-spa framework (framework used for microfrontend apps)?

Tags: micro-frontend, single-spa-angular, single-spa

My requirement is to register apps on dynamic routes (I need to get a UUID from server & append it to every MFE route). My approach is to first register a single MFE, get the UUID from server & then register other MFEs on dynamic routes. Is it possible to register MFEs after invoking start() method on the same single-spa instance ? If no , can I register those MFE's on another single-spa instance ? Will this impact the single-spa behaviour ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try this? What was the result?

Comment: Does this help ? https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa/issues/189